# How to get last values from arrays

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I am checking one line of code from my project

```
if ( (test == 0) &&
     lenght.Matches(new Version(Convert.ToInt64(version))) )
```

Whenever i debugged i am getting currentVersion as a constant value of 18 digit number,but the result i wanted is last exisitng datas version

i am getting '`length`' as using the following code

```
length.Version = (long)data.Version.Rows[0]["Version"];
```

So i suspect it is always taking Rows arrays first value, how can i change this code so that it will give the last value of arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using *LINQ-expression*

```
currentVersion.Version = (long)m_spodata.DataVersion.Rows.Last()["Version"];
```

Using `Rows.Count` property

```
currentVersion.Version = 
  (long) m_spodata.DataVersion.Rows[m_spodata.DataVersion.Rows.Count - 1]["Version"];
```

Comment: You are mising either a `.Length` or a `Count` or a `Count()` depending on whether `Rows` is an array, an `ICollection` or some other kind of `IEnumerable` in your second suggestion.

Comment: i was checking which is more opotimized one among the answers

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for

```
DataVersion.Rows[DataVersion.Count - 1]["Version"];
```

Answer (score 2):

This returns max version from rows:

```
m_spodata.DataVersion.Rows.Select(p => p["Version"]).Max();
```

This returns last element (by index) from array:

```
m_spodata.DataVersion.Rows.Last()["Version"];
```

Comment: i am using visual-studio 2005

Answer (score 1):

```
currentVersion.Version = 
    (long)m_spodata.DataVersion.Rows[m_spodata.DataVersion.Rows.Length-1]["Version"];
```